# How do I check if an USB drive is bootable?

Tags: virtual-machine, usb-drive

I just created an USB drive and would like to check if it's correctly bootable without rebooting my actual computer. How should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under Linux, you have to know which device path got the drive with for example with `dmesg | tail` after insertion, let's assume it's `/dev/sdb`.

### Qemu

`sudo qemu -hda /dev/sdb` or `sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /dev/sdb` for 64 bits.

---

### VirtualBox

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/usb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb
sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdb*
```

then add ~/usb.vmdk as a disk in a VM and boot on it

---

Don't hesitate to add other ways to do.

Comment: Note: qemu can wrongly finish on "fatal authentication error", then "init: respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes." but it doesn't happen on real machines.

Comment: You can also use the windows version of QEmu, if you only have windows.

Comment: Not sure why but the 'qemu' command doesn't work for me, I need: qemu-system-x86_64 or qemu-system-i386 depending on whether you want to boot a 64-bit or 32-bit VM (hint: you want 64-bit)

Answer (score 7):

While it won't show if the stuff on the filesystem is capable of handling the whole boot thing you can check the boot flag with `fdisk -l <drive>` from a shell on a reasonably good *nix. (Which essentially tells the bios if it should try to boot the thingie or not.)

Comment: What should ```fdisk -l <drive>``` output if or if not the drive is bootable?